# Count comma separated value passed as parameter to controller in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails

In the rails application, the textarea have the comma separated values and while saving the form. I want to save the the count of comma separated value to the database instead of the whole string. How to count this.
The textarea in view is:

```
<%= f.text_area :sent_to %>
```

The parameters being passed to the controller are:

```
 Parameters: {"utf8"=>"✓", "authenticity_token"=>"ag8WL59Swqo1TOFYfMOAC55VgoIxGSkleMXFDhUXYhO91zcPngas26MbpvMMyydNPSYntCfjAvKSh2R0TdQtbA==", "message_text"=>"    ", "sms_type"=>"true", "staff_type"=>"Teaching", "message"=>{"sent_to"=>"34434343243, 7869851872", "organization_id"=>"4"}, "contact_nos"=>["34434343243, 7869851872"], "contact_no"=>["34434343243", "7869851872"]}
```

Now the controller have message_params action

```
 def message_params
      params.require(:message).permit(:message_text, :sent_to, :no_of_message, :organization_id)
    end
```

Following is the create action to save the data

```
def create
    @message = Message.new(message_params)

    respond_to do |format|
      if @message.save
        format.html { redirect_to @message, notice: 'Message was successfully created.' }
        format.json { render :show, status: :created, location: @message }
      else
        format.html { render :new }
        format.json { render json: @message.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end
```

Thank you all for your answer, the problem is solved and one more thing I want the staff_type to be stored in sent_to. For this I did but it didn't worked. @message.sent_to = message_params[:message_text][:staff_type]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could do

```
def create
    @message = Message.new(message_params)
    @message.sent_to = @message.sent_to.try(:split,",").try(:count)
end
```

**Update**

From your comment I guess that, you want to save both `sent_to` count and `staff_type` in same attribute `sent_to`?? 
You can save only one at a time, Or you have to serialize the attribute and you can save `sent_to` and `staff_type` as an object. But if you have too many search queries using `sent_to` it is not recommended to use serialized column. 
 If you want to save `staff_type` alone, you should use

`@message.sent_to = params[:staff_type]`

Comment: your solution worked. I also want the staff_type to be stored in sent_to. For this I did but it didn't worked.
@message.sent_to = message_params[:message_text][:staff_type]

Answer (score 0):

This should work.

```
sent_to_count = message_params[:message][:sent_to].split(",").count
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
count = params[:message]['sent_to'].split(",").count
```

Hope this will work for you.

Answer (score 0):

You shouldn't perform such operation in controller. The more standard way is to perform this in your model. Create a before validation callback method and spite it to append count to its origin. In this way you wont have to worry about while updating same action from different levels of url.

Update your params permission:

```
before_validation: :append_send_to_count

def append_send_to_count
    if sent_to.present? and sent_to_changed?
       seld.sent_to_count = sent_to.split(',').size
    end
end
```

Answer (score 0):

storing other values along with sent_to

```
        number_array=params[:message][:sent_to]
        @final_array=[]
        number_array.split(",").flatten.compact.each do |number|
          @final_array << {:number => number, :staff_type => message_params[:message_text][:staff_type]}
          ##something like @final_array[0] will give
          ##{:123456=>123456,:staff_type=>Teaching}
          ##@final_array[0][:12345] will give 12345
          ##@final_array[0][:staff_type] will give "Teaching"
        end
```

Comment: that problem is solved, now I want the staff_type to be stored in sent_to. For this I did but it didn't worked. 
@message.sent_to = message_params[:message_text][:staff_type]

Comment: hi @AjeetKhan.i have updated my answer by adding staff-type as well..kindly check and let me know

Comment: its not working. I also wan the sms_type from the parameter to be saved in the database